# client-side unit testing on Google App Engine

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine

Is there a simple and straightforward tutorial on client-side (as in on your development workstation, using testbed and checking both backend functionality and rendered HTML) unit and integration testing on the Google App Engine Python SDK? Something I can point other developers to?

Comment: what do you mean by "client side" unit testing? testing the javascript?

Comment: Sorry. I should have made myself more clear. It's testing on the desktop development machine. Not necessarily through a test-runner like GAEUnit, but as close as possible to a minimal python+SDK install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a good way to do it, I built a tool that helps in assembling an environment (the App Engine SDK is not pip-installable) where it's easy to test the application:

https://github.com/rbanffy/testable_appengine

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial for [Local Unit Testing](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting) at developers.google.com is good.

Then, for the "rendered HTML" testing you probably want to look at Selenium. The IDE is a good start, but you'll want to move to WebDriver soon. The [WebDriver intro](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) at seleniumhq.org is a good start.